# Macro for giving all shapes on a page a common border

Tags: macros, coreldraw

I am using CorelDraw X7. I have a page containing many shapes and I wish to construct a macro to change it,
so that the bounding rectangle of alle shapes (the smallest one containing them all)
will have a common border of a given size.
I can find the size of the bounding rectangle and have tried to use the ActiveSelection.AlignAndDistribute sub
to move the shapes, but this sub has a lot of parameters, which I do not understand ("Help" does not help me).

My idea is this:

1. Specify the border, say pgBorder.
2. Get the width and height of the bounding rectangle, say shpsWidth and shpsHeight.
3. Move the shapes so that the lower left corner of the new bounding rectangle will have coordinates (pgBorder, pgBorder).
4. Reset the page size to shpsWidth + 2 * pgBorder resp. shpsHeight + 2 * pgBorder.

The shape bounding rectangle should now be surrounded with a border of size pgBorder.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub GivePageCommonBorder()
    Dim pgBorder As Double, shpsWidth As Double, shpsHeight As Double
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim pg As Page
 
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    doc.Unit = cdrMillimeter
    pgBorder = 20
    Set pg = doc.ActivePage
    ' Select all shapes on the page
    pg.Shapes.All.CreateSelection
    shpsWidth = ActiveSelection.SizeWidth
    shpsHeight = ActiveSelection.SizeHeight
    
    ' This is what I am lacking:
    ' Move the selection so its lower left corner has coordinates (pgBorder,pgBorder)
    
    ' Adjust page size
    pg.SizeWidth = shpsWidth + 2 * pgBorder
    pg.SizeHeight = shpsHeight + 2 * pgBorder
End Sub
```

Best wishes
Holger

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon the .Move method and constructed the following solution:

```
Sub GivePageCommonBorder()
    Dim pgBorder As Double
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim pg As Page
 
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    doc.Unit = cdrMillimeter
    pgBorder = 5
    Set pg = doc.ActivePage
    pg.Shapes.All.CreateSelection
    With ActiveSelection
        pg.SizeWidth = .SizeWidth + 2 * pgBorder
        pg.SizeHeight = .SizeHeight + 2 * pgBorder
        .Move pgBorder - .LeftX, pgBorder - .BottomY
    End With
End Sub
```

Holger